# Determining difference in timestamps for two values in the same MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I am relatively new to programming in PHP, so I apologize if this is a rather simple question.

I have a MySQL database table called MachineReports that contains the following values: ReportNum(primary key, auto increment), MachineID and Timestamp

Here is some example data:

```
|ReportNum | MachineID |     Timestamp      |
|1         | AD3203     | 2012-11-18 06:32:28|
|2         | AD3203     | 2012-11-19 04:00:15|
|3         | BC4300     | 2012-11-19 04:00:15|
```

What I am attempting to do is find the difference in timestamps in seconds for each machine ID by iterating over each row set. I am getting stuck on the best way to do this, however. Here is the code I've written so far:

```
<?php
include '../dbconnect/dbconnect.php';
      $machineID=[];

//Get a list of all MachineIDs in the database      
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT DISTINCT(MachineID) FROM MachineReports') as $row) {
        array_push($machineID, $row[0]);
   }

  for($i=0;$i<count($machineID);$i++){
    foreach($dbh->query("SELECT MachineID FROM MachineReports WHERE MachineID='$machineID[$i]' ORDER BY MachineID") as $row) {

    //code to associate each machineID with two time stamps goes here
 }
  }
```

?>
This code just lists out the contents of the table row by row. **My ultimate goal is to find the difference in timestamps for a certain MachineID.** One of the things I've considered is using a multidimensional array in php - using the $machineID as the key and then storing the timestamp inside the array the key points to.

However, I'm uncertain how to do that since my query parses row by row.

I have quite a few questions.

1) Is this the most efficient way to be doing this? I suspect my database table design may not be the best.
2)What would be the best way to determine the difference in timestamps for a certain machineID?

Even just a pointer to a topic that would prompt me to think about this in a different way would be helpful - I'm not afraid to do research. Thanks!

Comment: What database library are you using here? Seeing naked variables in your query string is *not* encouraging.

Comment: how many lines per machine do you have? will it always be 2 lines?

Comment: what output are you looking for based on your data sample

Comment: @tadman - if you have suggestions on how I can improve my approach, I'd be very happy to hear them. Learning best practices is part of my goal.

EyalAlsheich - the lines per machine can vary between 0 to 2 lines. Eventually I hope to have logic that will notify the user when there are not 2 lines.

DrewPierce - My eventual final results will be the difference in timestamps in seconds for a given ID. I plan to use this data farther down the script.

Comment: You should have a look at [SQL escaping techniques](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to see how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solution assumed you want 1 row per machine so that could be a big assumption! you could use the now() function against the max of ts. if you list what sample output you would expect we could tweak the answers.

you could create a temporary table and with machineid and maxts and prior ts. last two columns as null. insert a row for every distinct machineid. then update each row maxts as its max of ts. the update each row for priorts being the row max ts prior to maxts. then u have your data

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
reportnum int not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
machineid char(10) not null,
ts TIMESTAMP
);
 insert into t1 (machineid,ts) select 'AD3203','2012-11-18 06:32:28';
 insert into t1 (machineid,ts) select 'AD3203','2012-11-19 04:00:15';
 insert into t1 (machineid,ts) select 'BC4300','2012-11-19 04:00:15';

CREATE TABLE temp_rpt (
machineid char(10) not null,
maxts TIMESTAMP null,
priorts TIMESTAMP null
);

  insert into temp_rpt (machineid,maxts,priorts)
 select distinct machineid,null,null from t1;



UPDATE temp_rpt
SET maxts = 
  ( SELECT MAX(ts) 
    FROM t1
    WHERE machineid = temp_rpt.machineid
  )

UPDATE temp_rpt
SET priorts = 
  ( SELECT MAX(ts) 
    FROM t1
    WHERE machineid = temp_rpt.machineid
    and ts<temp_rpt.maxts
  )

 select * from temp_rpt;
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| machineid | maxts               | priorts             |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| AD3203    | 2012-11-19 04:00:15 | 2012-11-18 06:32:28 |
| BC4300    | 2012-11-19 04:00:15 | NULL                |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

then do your date math

Comment: @JayRizzo03 I think it best to have sql handle it then drop the table

Comment: I like this idea very much. I will give this a try this evening when I'm off work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I entirely understand what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to calculate the time difference between each row of the table where the MachineID is the same I believe something like the following should do what you need.

NOTE:  This finds the time difference between each row (of the same MachineID, it resets to 00:00:00 with each new MachineID).  If you wanted the total between the first and the last row you'd have to sum the TimestampDiff values.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tMachineReportsTest;
CREATE TABLE tMachineReportsTest (
    ReportNum INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    MachineID VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    Timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ReportNum),
    UNIQUE KEY (MachineId, Timestamp)
);

INSERT INTO tMachineReportsTest VALUES
(NULL,'AD3203','2012-11-18 06:32:28'),
(NULL,'AD3203','2012-11-18 10:45:13'),
(NULL,'BC4300','2012-11-19 04:00:15'),
(NULL,'AD3203','2012-11-19 11:19:23'),
(NULL,'BC4300','2012-11-20 06:08:01'),
(NULL,'AD3203','2012-11-20 18:04:45')
;

SET @machineId     := NULL;
SET @lastMachineId := NULL;
SET @lastTimestamp := NULL;

SELECT x.ReportNum, x.MachineId, x.Timestamp, x.TimestampDiff FROM (
    SELECT
        tMRT.ReportNum,
        tMRT.MachineId,
        tMRT.Timestamp,
        @lastMachineId := @machineId AS _lastMachineId,
        @machineId     := tMRT.machineId AS _machineId,
        CASE WHEN @lastMachineId IS NULL OR @lastMachineId = @machineId THEN TIMEDIFF(tMRT.Timestamp, IFNULL(@lastTimestamp, tMRT.Timestamp)) ELSE '00:00:00' END TimestampDiff,
        @lastTimestamp := tMRT.Timestamp lastTimestamp
    FROM
        tMachineReportsTest tMRT
    ORDER BY
        tMRT.MachineId, tMRT.Timestamp
) x
;
```

Output from the resulting query looks like the following:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------+
| ReportNum | MachineId | Timestamp           | TimestampDiff |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------+
|         1 | AD3203    | 2012-11-18 06:32:28 | 00:00:00      |
|         2 | AD3203    | 2012-11-18 10:45:13 | 04:12:45      |
|         4 | AD3203    | 2012-11-19 11:19:23 | 24:34:10      |
|         6 | AD3203    | 2012-11-20 18:04:45 | 30:45:22      |
|         3 | BC4300    | 2012-11-19 04:00:15 | 00:00:00      |
|         5 | BC4300    | 2012-11-20 06:08:01 | 26:07:46      |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you - I see the value of this approach as well.